# access to $_POST

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['s1']))
{
$uname=$_SESSION['s2'];
echo "<b><i>hello ".$_SESSION['s1'];
echo "</b></i>";

}
else{
$name="none";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Doctor</title>
<form method="post">
<?php

$connection=Mysql_connect('localhost','admin','123');
Mysql_select_db('db',$connection);
//agar patient list ro khast

if(array_key_exists('sub3',$_POST))
{                      

                if(!$connection)
                {
                        echo 'connection is invalid';
                }
                else
                {

                        $query="select * from pnt";
                        $result=mysql_query($query);
                        $num=Mysql_num_rows($result);
                        $num1=Mysql_num_fields($result);

                if($num>0)
                {
                echo "<table border=0>";
                echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Family</td><td>File</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
                for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
                {
                $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);

                for($j=0;$j<$num1;$j++)
                {
                echo"<td>$row[$j]</td>";       
                }
                echo"<td><input type='submit' name='sub6' value='$row[0]'/></td>
                <td><img src='file.jpg' width='50' height='50' /></td>";
                echo"</tr>";
                }//for

                echo"</table>";
                }//if

                }//else

exit();
}
//agar zado clinical filo khast
if(array_key_exists('sub6',$_POST))
{

$query1="select * from patient where id=".$_POST['sub6'];
$result1=mysql_query($query1);

$num2=Mysql_num_rows($result1);
$num3=Mysql_num_fields($result1);
                if($num2>0)
                {
                echo "<table border=2>";
                for($i=0;$i<$num2;$i++)
                {
                $row=mysql_fetch_row($result1);


                echo"<td>id</td><td>name</td><td>Lastname</td><td>Info</td><td>Sympthoms</td><td>Diagnosis</td>";
                echo "<tr>";
                for($j=0;$j<$num3;$j++)
                {
                echo"<td>$row[$j]</td>";       
                }
                echo"</tr>";
                }//for
                echo"</table>";
                }//if
                        $query2="select * from pharmacies";
                        $result2=mysql_query($query2);
                        $nump=Mysql_num_rows($result2);

echo "Please Select a Pharmacy:<select ID=2 name='ph'>";
echo"<option >select please";
for($i=0;$i<$nump;$i++)
{
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result2);
echo"<option value=$row[1]>$row[1]";
echo"</option>";
}
echo"</SELECT>";       
$query2="select * from pharmacy";
$result2=mysql_query($query2);
$nump=Mysql_num_rows($result2);

echo "Please Select Drug:<select ID=1 name='dg'>";
echo"<option >select please";
for($i=0;$i<$nump;$i++)
{
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result2);
echo"<option  >$row[0]";
echo"</option>";
}
echo"</SELECT>";       
echo"<input type='submit' name='insert' value='insert this drug'/>";
echo"<b>Quantity:<input type='text' name='txt1'/>";
exit();
}//if
if(array_key_exists('insert',$_POST))
{
$qname="select * from pnt where id=".$_POST['sub6'];
$resname=mysql_query($qname);
$rown=mysql_fetch_row($resname);
$na=$rown[1];
$ins="insert into request(drug,qty,ph,situation,Doctor,userp)values('".$_POST['dg']."',".$_POST['txt1'].",'".$_POST['ph']."','underprocess','$uname','$na')";
echo $ins;
$rlt=mysql_query($ins);
if (!$rlt)
{
print(mysql_errno() .":". mysql_error());
}
}

if(array_key_exists('insert',$_POST))
{
$in="select * from request";
$rslt=mysql_query($in);
if (!$rslt)
{
print(mysql_errno() .":". mysql_error());
}

$num2=Mysql_num_rows($rslt);
$num3=Mysql_num_fields($rslt);
                if($num2>0)
                {
                echo "<table border=2>";
                echo"<td>id</td><td>drug</td><td>quantity</td><td>Doctor</td><td>explanation</td><td>pharmacy</td>";
                for($i=0;$i<$num2;$i++)
                {
                $row=mysql_fetch_row($rslt);

                echo "<tr>";
                for($j=0;$j<$num3;$j++)
                {
                echo"<td>$row[$j]</td>";       
                }
                echo"</tr>";
                }//for
                echo"</table>";
                }//if
}
if(array_key_exists('sub4',$_POST))
{
header("location:login.php");
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="sub3" value="patient list"/>
<input type="submit" name="sub4" value="sign out"/>
<img src="Doc.jpg" />
</form>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: "I don't have access to $_POST['sub6'] because it is just in array_key_exists('sub6',$_POST)" makes no sense.

Comment: `$_POST['sub6']` is apparently blank.  Check the code you're using to POST to this page, and make sure you're sending the right data.  `array_key_exists` might say `$_POST['sub6']` exists, but that doesn't mean it has a value.

Comment: Also, for the love of god, SQL INJECTION!

Comment: Nope... @Negin, try posting the results of print_r($_POST).  That would give us a bit more to work with.

Comment: P.S. Don't use `$_POST` variables directly in SQL queries.  Escape the values.  Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: but the error is this:Undefined index: sub6 in D:\phpweb\Doctor.php on line 124 it can't even find it

Comment: may i edit the code to show all the location of sub6?(it is long you will complain) but let me do it please!

Comment: @Negin use `pastebin` and post the link.

Comment: fardjad what you mean with pastebin?

Comment: @Negin: It helps to show the error in the question.  That helps us answer you.  Also, check the code you're using to POST to this page, and make sure you're sending the right data.

Comment: @Rocket I am sure about my code my code can work but I just insert the part that i have question,ok now i will edit it for you guys

Comment: i didn't use pastebin but i edited my code for you because just i didn't used the function mysql_real_escape_string i'm sure abt my code

Comment: ok now i used pastebin i must copy paste in here from there yes?

Comment: for people that are new to this post error is here:$ins="insert into request(drug,qty,ph,situation,Doctor,userp)values('".$_POST['dg']."',".$_POST['txt1'].",'".$_POST['ph']."','underprocess','$uname','$na')"; $_POST can't be defined

Answer (score 3):

$_POST is a global, or rather 'super global'. It should be accessible anywhere in your script, including inside conditional statements, functions and classes.

Are you SURE $_POST['sub6'] is set?

On an unrelated side-note, don't please ever do this:

```
$qname="select * from pnt where id=".$_POST['sub6'];
```

Assigning values from $_POST without filtering it for proper values is one of the most common vulnerabilities in php scripting.

Comment: ok i will filter it,but here is the error:Undefined index: sub6 in D:\phpweb\Doctor.php on line 124

Answer (score 2):

You enter this condition only when "insert" is a key in POST.
Then you try to make a query using "sub6", which *may* not be set.
You simply have to test that "sub6" exists before using it in a query (like the rest of the keys of $_POST)

Comment: I didn't understand your mean.You mean i must use if(array_key_exists(....))) for sub6? where?

Comment: Here: if(array_key_exists('insert',$_POST)) ....

replace with:

    if(array_key_exists('insert',$_POST) && array_key_exists('sub6',$_POST)) ....

But you may have other problems if you use "dg", "txt1" or others vars not tested.

Basically, just don't think vars are set (posted) if you're not sure of it.  And use mysql_real_escape_string() as other posters said.

Comment: i used your solution it even don't go to if statement for one time

Comment: you are right thank you very much but how can i correct it  now it hasn't error but how can i force it to go to if?

Comment: You cannot force to enter a IF statement unless all the conditions are true.  In your current code, it appears that when 'insert' is set, then 'sub6' is not.  You won't be able to make your insert query is 'sub6' is not set when you receive the data.

Comment: I knew it from scratch but i didn't know how to solve it i can transfer my code to another page and call header and use sessions but just i didn't want to do that because i didn't want now i think i must do it!